# Drawing UML class diagram for a blogging system

Tags: class, uml, class-diagram

I'm trying to draw the correspond UML class diagram of the use case diagram of a simple blogging system, which is displayed as follows:
[image]

To draw the class diagram, there should be two classes: User and Blog. But I have difficult drawing the association between them because there could be two different multiplicities in the relations between those two classes. For example, when user create a blog, the class diagram would look like this:
[image]

But in terms of user viewing blog, the multiplicity is different as a certain blog can be viewed by not only 1 user, so the class diagram would look like this:
[image]

So how can I solve this issue in solution domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Thomas' answer:

- One sure thing is the structural 1 to many relation between `User` and `Blog`.  But this is more implicit knowledge than use-case analysis:  your system MUST keep track of the link of a `Blog` and the `User` who created it, so to enable him also later updates and deletes.
- However, many blogging systems also keep track of the `Blogs` that a `User` did consult (to measure audience, to keep track of history, etc...). So your system COULD also keep track of the viewing (but it could also work without).

[image]

You could show the navigation arrow.  But in your system, the navigation will certainly be bidirectional.

---

A more systematic approach to the use case analysis is to use the [entity- control-boundary](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/lectures/ooa/analysis/ecb.htm) approach, and use the following classes for the design:

- Entities:    persistent data:  `Blog` and `User` as above
- Boundaries:  link between a use case and actors:  `CreateOwnBlog` and `ViewBlog`
- Control:     mediating classes between the two worlds:  `ViewingSubsystem` and `AuthoringSubsystem`

Answer (score 1):

The association between classes does not show the action which is taken. It just shows that they are related.

The `Create` and `View` are different actions taken by `User`. The `Create` will most likely refer to a server which has a `create` method and also a `retrieveBlog` so it can be shown (which a view will manage).

Use a sequence diagram to show the behavioral part (like I suggested in the answer to your other question).

Comment: Sorry for later reply as I'm very busy recently. I think the association between classes should be determined by the attributes of them. For instance, if the `Blog` class has a attribute named Owner to store the `User` who creates it, then the 'Create' association should be there. And if `Blog` has another collection attribute named Visitors to store the collection of  `User` have viewed it, then the `View` association also make sense.

Comment: You are not using associations the way they should. They are not about behavior. I can recommend reading Geerts blog about associations: https://bellekens.com/2011/08/10/uml-best-practice-attribute-or-association/

Comment: The article you given doesn't make it clear to me due to its poor readability I think, but we don't need to discuss it too much and should go back to the topic. In my understanding so far, whether there should be a certain association or not really depends on the system requirements. If, in my case, the system is required to keep track of the `Blog` that a `User` view by ways like storing the collection of `User` (Visitors) in the `Blog`, then the viewing association makes sense. Otherwise it shouldn't exist.

Comment: Have a look at Christophe's answer.